Compatibility issue with Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS and .NET 8.0 for iOS 17.5
Build fails with NU1202 error for Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS despite working in Visual Studio and simulator
Given that the package is working in Visual Studio and the app runs successfully on the simulator,
I am encountering a build failure while trying to compile my iOS project using .NET 8.0 targeting iOS 17.5 in VS Code. The error message is as follows:
Build FAILED.
iOS.csproj : error NU1202: Package Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS 2.8.3.1 is not compatible with net8.0-ios17.5 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS 2.8.3.1 supports: xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
.iOS.csproj : error NU1202: Package Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS 2.8.3.1 is not compatible with net8.0-ios17.5 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) / iossimulator-arm64. Package Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS 2.8.3.1 supports: xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
Questions:
Is there a way to make this package compatible with .NET 8.0 and iOS 17.5?
Are there any alternative packages or workarounds that I could use for integrating a calendar in my project with these target frameworks?
Is there a way to downgrade the project to a compatible framework, or is there a better approach to resolving this issue?
Tried:
I added the following property to my project file (.csproj):
<PropertyGroup>
  <ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>true</ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
  <PackageReference Include="Naxam.FSCalendar.iOS" Version="2.8.3.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-iossimulator'">
  <!-- Add simulator-specific references if needed -->
</ItemGroup>

Environment:
.NET 8.0
iOS 17.5
Visual Studio Code

I think that last TargetFramework moniker is wrong; I think you can only use net8.0-ios

I had to update Visual Studio to get past this problem.
Your error looks like the package is built for Xamarin, but not .NET for iOS. Check if there's an updated version of the package that does support .NET 8, or build the source yourself (if you have access to it).
